# question about sets and their intersection/union

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $A$,$B$ and $C$ are sets in a universal set $U$,

Show that:
$$(A \cap B) \cup C=A \cap (B \cup C) $$ **if and only if**
$$C \subset A. $$

Also if 
$$A \subset C , \  B\subset C , \  A\cup B=C , \ \mbox{ and } \  A \cap B=\emptyset,$$
then
$$ A=C-B. $$

I tried to solve, but unfortunately couldn't be successful, any hint or some help would be so appreciated.

Comment: Your parenthesis are mismatched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$C \subseteq (A \cap B) \cup C = A \cap (B \cup C) \subseteq A$

Conversely if C subset A, then
$(A \cap B) \cup C = (A \cup C) \cap (B \cup C) = A \cap (B \cup C)$

Answer (score 0):

As to question (2) , an attempt using algebra of sets laws.

[image]